# validate form input type file type using jquery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, validation

the following code:
script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formElem").validate({

        rules: {  

            dimage:{
                minlength:200    
            }  
        },
messages: {


             dimage:{
               required: 'Please select the image!'  
            } ,

        }       
    });

});
</script>
```

html code

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">

 <input type="file" name="dimage" id="dimage" />
</form>
```

I'm using jquery validate.js file for client side validation. when i create a file with above code it's not showing any error message.

How should i alert the error message when the user not selected the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#formElem").validate({
        rules: {  
            dimage:{
                required: true    
            }  
        },
        messages: {
            dimage:{
               required: 'Please select the image!'  
            } ,
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: how to validate image with type(png and jpg) with min and max size

Answer (score 5):

If your uploading an image file Jquery Validation plugin have a option `accept` you can set that to a value which will validate that if the file is really an image then your jquery code will be like this:

```
$("#formElem").validate({

      rules: {  

            dimage:{
                    required: true,
                    accept:"jpg,png,jpeg,gif"
                }  
        },
    messages: {

            dimage:{
                    required: "Select Image",
                    accept: "Only image type jpg/png/jpeg/gif is allowed"
                }  

             }      
        });
```

for more information See [Official Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/accept)

Comment: **Note:** This method used to look at just the filename, specifically the file extension. That behaviour is now available as the "extension" method inside src/additional/extension.js. [See](https://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/).